# Mapping an MSSQL Login to the secondary replica in a High Availability Group

Tags: sql-server, security, logins

I'm trying to map a login to a user in a database on the secondary replica of a two node High Availability group.  Obviously this fails since the replica is offline.  Is there a way for me to create the login mappings to users to the offline database?  I'm using Windows domain accounts BTW, so no SID issues, just the mapping problem.

When connecting to the secondary, after a failover, the error is that "the users' default database could not be accessed." The default database is the one where on the primary I set the login to have the correct database mappings, and the correct default database. When the failover happens, the default database is correct, but the user is not mapped to the database. At all. I know these mappings are at the database level which is why this is throwing me for a loop.

Comment: Can you supply the code you're using and the error message? What do you mean the replica is "offline"?

Comment: The user itself should be replicated from the primary also - have you created the login on the secondary server using WITH SID and the SID from sys.sql_logins on the primary?

Comment: The secondary database in a High Availability group is always offline.  I'm using Windows accounts so the SID issue isn't the problem.  The login is created on the secondary.  On a failover the user's default database comes over, but the database mappings do not.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using.The secondary DB in an availability group shouldn't be offline.It should either be Recovering or Synchronised depending on whether Read Only Routing has been configured.

Comment: The existence of a user in a database with the same sid as a login *is* the mapping. There's no further mapping to do.

Comment: Agreed, it's just that the mapping doesn't carry over after a failover.  The database is synchronized on the secondary, but it is not accessible, sql marks it as offline because it is receiving data from the primary.  I can mark it read only but that's not going to help.  This is driving me nuts, cause these mappings should be coming over with it.

Comment: @RichardWolford we need those error messages and the output of SELECT dbname FROM sys.syslogins where name = YourLoginName from the primary if we are going to be of any more help here.

Comment: SELECT dbname FROM sys.syslogins where name='hhq\c62125' produces no results on the primary or the secondary.

Comment: @RichardWolford then your login isn't present. That's a problem. Are you 100% sure the row isn't in there? Could you do a SELECT * to try find it?

Comment: @RichardWolford just as an idea, see if the row is present under sys.sql_logins - you may have accidentally created a SQL login rather than a Windows user.

Comment: on both the primary and secondary, run this command and add the results to your question via the [edit] link:  `select * from sys.server_principals sp where sp.name = N'login_name_here';`  (replace "login name here" with the actual login name,)

Comment: The login doesn't appear in sys.sql_logins,but it does appear under server_serverprincipals, and it appears under security\logins.  I tried to delete the login and add it back, but sql is telling me that it is already there.  This is a bit of a mystery to me.

Answer (score 1):

If the login is a Windows login, and is present on both the Primary and Secondary servers, you should only need to add the database user to the Primary Replica.

This is because database users are at the database level and the creation of the user itself will be replicated to the secondary replica. As this is a Windows login, it then follows that the SID will already match.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought should be happening, but it doesn't seem to be doing so.  Honestly I'm really confused as to what could be going wrong.  Any idea on what I could check?

Comment: @RichardWolford when you say it isn't happening, what do you mean? What error message are you getting?

Comment: When connecting to the secondary, after a failover, the error is that "the users' default database could not be accessed."  The default database is the one where on the primary I set the login to have the correct database mappings, and the correct default database.  When the failover happens, the default database is correct, but the user is not mapped to the database.  At all.  I know these mappings are at the database level which is why this is throwing me for a loop.\